# How to get/Query last successful Sync date in QuickBooks Desktop?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, ipp-qbd-sync

I have a requirement to get last successful sync date (Sync manager : Successful Sync) from QuickBooks desktop edition.

Which API and Object reference do I need to use?

Comment: you can get the above info from this file(desktop local)
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Intuit\SyncManager\SyncManager.sch

Answer (score 1):

Please use SyncActivity API:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/syncactivity

For individual objects query the SyncStatus API:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/syncstatus